# Does matrix $S_k-H_ky_k=0$?

Tags: matrices, optimization

The teaching assistant marked down one part of my assignment. What I wrote is $(S_k-H_ky_k)^Ty_j=0$, for any $j=0,1,...,k-1$, $k$ can be very large, so that $S_k-H_ky_k=0$. Since this equation satisfies for every $y_j$, thus the only way to make it is $S_k-H_ky_k=0$, is there anything I missed?

Some context information, give $f(x)=\frac{1}2x^TAx-b^Tx$, where $A$ is a positive definite matrix and $x$ is a vector, find the minimum using Quasi-Newton DFP method. $H_k$ is the update defined in Quasi-Newton DFP method, for [details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davidon%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Powell_formula). Since the target function is quadratic, then $y_k=AS_k$. $S_k=x_{k+1}-x_k$ describes an update process for finding the optimal. Then $y_j$ can be written as $y_j=AS_j=A(x_{k+1}-x_k)$.

My understanding is that, $y_j$ basically can be any vector, then it is indeed a question asking if vector $v=0$ given $v^Ty=0$ where $y$ is any vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prove that $span \left\{ y_0, \ldots, y_{k}\right\}=\mathbb{R}^k$ or make use of some other properties.

This is not true for general $y_i$. For example, if you let all of the $y_i=0$, then your claim is not true.